# Is it possible to turn off Dropbox's file-labelling?

Tags: windows, dropbox

Dropbox labels files with a "✓" if they completed syncing, with an "x" if there's some problem, etc.

[image: Dropbox labelling files]

These labels are very annoying because in order to maintain their accuracy, the Dropbox app frequently refreshes the folder window.

For example:

- If you are in the middle of editing a file's name, it will finish your session and give the file just the part of the name that you were typing up to that point.
- If you scroll through the folder, the refresh will return you back up to the top of the folder.

Is there any way to get the Dropbox app to stop maintaining these labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the Dropbox shell extension using [ShExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Note that you might lose a large part of Dropbox functionality. (I don't know what exactly the shell extension is responsible for.)

Answer (score 0):

Exit dropbox while working on the files, then reopen it. Or just disconnect from the Internet temporarily

Comment: I hope I won't have to resort to that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide Dropbox's overlay icons, but the process is different depending on your operating system. I was able to find instructions on disabling the icon on Windows and Mac.

### Windows

> 1. Open Windows Registry Editor (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type in `regedit`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
> 2. Then go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`
> 3. Under `ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` key you will find keys of Dropbox, SkyDrive, and any other service that you may have installed
>      on your computer.
>
> [image: DropboxExt1 in regedit]
>
> 4. For Dropbox, simply rename the key `DropboxExt1` to something like `DropboxExt1-D` so Windows cannot find the key value in the registry.
> 5. Once done, restart your computer, or restart explorer using Task Manager.
>
> That’s it. You won’t find any more overlay icons on your synced files.
>   To get the icons back, remove the text that you appended on the
>   key(s).

- [Via SumTips.com](http://sumtips.com/2012/10/remove-green-check-mark-icon-overlay.html)

---

### Mac OS

> Open Finder and locate the Dropbox application, which you likely have
>   stored in your Applications folder. Right-click on it and select
>   **Show Package Contents**.
>
> [image: Dropbox in finder]
>
> You'll see a lone folder titled **Contents**. Open it and then open
>   the **PlugIns** folder. Inside the PlugIns folder will be a lone file,
>   **garcon.appex**. Right-click on this file and again select **Show Package Contents**.
>
> [image: garcon.appex in finder]
>
> Again, you'll see a lone folder titled **Contents**. Open it and then
>   open the **Resources** folder. Inside will be a number of folders and
>   four overlay files. Change the name of the **overlay-uptodate.icns**
>   file, which is the file for the green check mark icons. I just added
>   edit to the end of it. This way, if I find I miss the feeling of
>   warmth and security that green sea of check marks provides, I can just
>   go back and remove my edit suffix and return the file name to its
>   original name, thus restoring Dropbox's green check marks in Finder.
>
> [image: Green checkbox icon file]
>
> You will need to relaunch Finder for the change to take effect. Hold
>   down the **Option** key and right-click the Finder icon in the Dock,
>   and then click **Relaunch**.
>
> [image: Relaunching Finder]
>
> When Finder returns, your Dropbox folder will be free of the green
>   check marks.
>
> [image: Dropbox without green checkmarks]

- [Via cnet.com](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/get-rid-of-dropboxs-green-check-mark-icons-in-os-x-finder/)